# How to have validates_inclusion_of when u have another 2 field that's up to user to select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have 3 options for user to select which looks like this:
[image]

User can only choose 1 out of the 3. However i want to include validates_inclusion_of for the 3rd method so that only a few letters are acceptable. So i included this in my model.

```
 validates_inclusion_of :user_seq, :in => %w(A T G C R Y S W K M B D H V N)
```

However, after adding this, i can't get any return value from the form no matter whether i choose randomly / Specified ATGC/ Seating, i don't get anything back from it because  of the
`validates_inclusion_of :user_seq, :in => %w(A T G C R Y S W K M B D H V N)` code. IF i remove them, then i get my results

**form**

```
<legend><strong>Method Use :</strong></legend><br>  
            <h3 align="left"><font size ="5"><b>Step 1: <u>Choose only ONE of the methods</u></font></b></h3> 
        <table class="p_gen">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="method1"><label>Randomly</label><br />
                <%= radio_button_tag(:choice,'Randomly',checked:true )%>
                <p> ( Generate a primer randomly )</p></th>

                <th class="method2"><label>Specified ATGC</label><br />
                <%= radio_button_tag(:choice,'Specified ATGC')%> 
                <p> ( Generate a primer with number of A,T,G and C )</p></th>

                <th class="method3"><label>Seating</label><br />
                <%= radio_button_tag(:choice,'Seating')%> 
                <p> ( Generate a primer according to your preference )</p></th>
             </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td class="method1">
                    <p> Input length of the primer you want : </p>
                    <label>Primer Length :</label>
                    <%= f.number_field(:primer_length , min: 6 , max: 35)%>
                </td>
                <td class="method2">
                    <p>Input the number of each base the primer should have</p>
                    <label>Number of A :</label>
                    <%= number_field_tag(:no_A,nil, in:0...36) %><br />
                    <label>Number of T :</label>
                    <%= number_field_tag(:no_T,nil, in:0...36) %><br />
                    <label>Number of G :</label>
                    <%= number_field_tag(:no_G,nil, in:0...36) %><br />
                    <label>Number of C :</label>
                    <%= number_field_tag(:no_C,nil, in:0...36) %><br />
                    Total bases:<span></span>
                </td>   
                <td class="method3">
                    <p> Input your preference sequence (only IUPAC nucleotide).</p>
                    <p><b><u>IUPAC Nucleotide :</u></b></p>
                    <p>A,T,G,C,R,Y,S,W,K,M,B,D,H,V,N </p>
                    Example: <br /> 
                    Preference primer = TAGGCT<b>N</b>TTA<b>N</b>GAC<b>N</b> <br />
                    N = Any base ( A/ T / G / C) <br /><br />               
                    <label>Desired sequence :</label><br>
                    <%= text_field_tag(:user_seq,nil,:min=>6, :maxlength=>35)%>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </fieldset>
        <br>

        <fieldset class ="sample">
        <h4><font size="5"><b>Step 2: <u>Choose 'Yes' if you want to input reference sequence for Binding-time analysis </font></u></b></h4> 
        <legend><strong>Do you have NCBI data to extract / FASTA file to input?</strong></legend><br>
            <label>Yes</label>
            <%= radio_button_tag(:result_choice,'Yes')%> 
            <label>No</label>
            <%= radio_button_tag(:result_choice,'No')%>
        <br>
        </fieldset>

        <br><div class = "button"> 
           <%=f.submit("Generate", :class => "Gbutton_class") %>
        </div>  
    <%end %>    
<%end%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do that with condition

```
validates_inclusion_of :user_seq, :in => %w(A T G C R Y S W K M B D H V N), if: :choice_is_seating?

def choice_is_seating?
 choice == "seating"
end
```

Comment: how can i see the error ? My program is not giving proper error of wat's going on. Is it bcoz of my form part where by i used tag when i'm using form_for? If i didn't use_tag then return value will be nil.

Comment: I'm now trying to put some error code in it . TO finalize them before i go for my project presentation in 4 weeks time

Comment: which controller i have to see

Comment: Generator controller.

Comment: ? it's already there. Could u help me check the form in generator view ? bcoz whenever i didn't use _tag i get empty return value. That's why i use _tag when i'm using form_for

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43694/discussion-between-nitinj-and-bc2)

Comment: Is there a way to prompt the error before clicking submit button ? I owuld like to try use Ajax . DO u think it's possible to include it here ?

Comment: Just add remote true in form tag and your form will be saved by ajax

Comment: Ok then how can i prompt the validation error ? Is it possilbe to prompt the error before clicking submit button ? FOr example number_field_tag will prompt to you the min and max number acceptable when u click submit before creating the object.